# Solve the differential equation $y'-xy^2 = 2xy$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, differential

I get it to the form $\left | \dfrac{y}{y+2} \right |=e^{x^2}e^{2C}$ but I'm not sure how to get rid of the absolute value and then solve for y. I've heard the absolute value can be ignored in differential equations. Is this true?

Comment: You can realize the left hand side as being $\dfrac{1}{1+\frac{2}{y}}$. Cross multiply to solve for $y$.

Comment: @CameronWilliams that fixes the algebra problem, but how to get rid of that absolute value

Comment: I think you might need initial value information but I haven't thought about it much.

Comment: @CameronWilliams because those appear when I'm doing integrals of 1/y and such, no initial information.

Comment: By promoting the constant $e^{2C}$, which by construction is sticktly positive, to a general constant you cover the case of the term inside the absolute value being negative.

Comment: @Winther so $e^{2C}$ = C does the trick? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Yes. To see that this works write $|y/(y+2)| = \epsilon y/(y+2)$ where $\epsilon = \pm 1$ to get that the right hand side becomes $\epsilon e^{2C}$ which is a general constant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the differential equation $$\frac{dy}{dx} = xy(y+2) $$ has two constant solutions $y = 0$ and $y = -2.$ the right hand side is continuous everywhere and satisfies Lipschitz condition everywhere so that it satisfies the uniqueness criteria. what this means for the solutions of this differential equation is that the solutions are  trapped in the three regions $y < -2, -2 < y < 0$ and $0 < y.$ that is, if it starts in one, then it stays there.

now you can happily separate the variables and get an explicit solution for $y.$

$\bf edit:$

by separation of variable you have arrived at $$|\frac{y}{y+2}| = \frac{1}{D}e^{x^2}$$  you can rewrite this as $$\frac{y+2}{y} = Ce^{-x^2}, y = \dfrac{2}{Ce^{-x^2} - 1}$$ this will take care of staying in each particular region.

Comment: so basically you are saying I can drop the absolute value sign and just keep working?

Comment: @Tyler, see the edit. you were right that you can drop the absolute value signs.

Answer (score 1):

If $|A|=B$, then $A$ must be either $B$ or $-B$, so your equation is equivalent to
$$
\frac{y}{y+2}=\pm e^{2C} e^{x^2}
.
$$
Now let $D=\pm e^{2C}$ and solve for $y$. (Since $C$ is an arbitrary constant, $D$ will be an arbitrary *nonzero* constant.)

Answer (score 0):

We have
$$y' - x{y^2} = 2xy \Rightarrow y' - 2xy = x{y^2} \Rightarrow y'.{y^{ - 2}} - 2x{y^{ - 1}} = x,\,\,\left( {y \ne 0} \right).$$
Put $z=y^{-1}$. Then
$$\begin{gathered}
  z' + 2xz =  - x \Rightarrow \frac{d}{{dx}}\left( {z{e^{{x^2}}}} \right) =  - x{e^{{x^2}}} \\
\Rightarrow z = {e^{ - {x^2}}}\int {\left( { - x{e^{{x^2}}}} \right)dx}  =  - \frac{1}{2}{e^{ - {x^2}}}\int {{e^{{x^2}}}d\left( {{x^2}} \right)}  \hfill \\
   =  - \frac{1}{2}{e^{ - {x^2}}}\left( {{e^{{x^2}}} + C} \right) =  - \frac{1}
{2} - \frac{C}{2}{e^{ - {x^2}}}. \hfill \\ 
\end{gathered} .$$
Finally, 
$$y = {z^{ - 1}} = \frac{1}{z} = \frac{1}{{ - \frac{1}{2} - \frac{C}{2}{e^{ - {x^2}}}}} =  - \frac{2}{{1 + C{e^{ - {x^2}}}}}.$$
Note: $y=0$ is also a solution of the equation.